# Huge size output in /proc/smaps

Tags: linux

I'm looking at /proc//smaps for a program compiled with libasan (-fsanitize=address).
I see some massive sizes and I'm trying to understand what it means.
For example:

```
2008fff7000-10007fff8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:           15032123396 kB
Rss:              142592 kB
Pss:              142592 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:    142592 kB
Referenced:       142592 kB
Anonymous:        142592 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me nr dd nh
```

Total size adds up to 21,475,147,836K

I'm using Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03 with kernel 4.4.19-29.55.amzn1.x86_64

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASAN works by reserving one byte (known as a shadow byte) per 8 bytes of user memory. The shadow bytes are checked on every memory access and updated on every change in allocation status.

Processes running on Linux on x86_64 have about 2^47 bytes of addressable space available, so ASAN maps around 2^47*1/9 ~= 15TB for these shadow bytes.

This is the mapping you're seeing.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how the shadow bytes work. What does this mean in terms of actual memory use that will eventually cause my host to run out of memory?

Comment: In your paste, the program uses 142592kB RAM out of the 15TB map for shadow bytes. The ASAN memory overhead is generally 2-4x, of which shadow bytes in this mapping is only a small fraction. Programs that frequently allocate and deallocate use disproportionately more memory, because ASAN avoids re-using memory areas to allow catching use-after-free bugs.

Comment: Which of the attributes in this paste refers to memory actually used? This is just a snippet of the smaps output, and in the past I was just adding up the 'Size' attribute to get a sense of total memory used.

Comment: "Size" is the amount of virtual address space reserved for this segment. "Rss" is the amount of RAM actually being used. The best number to add up is "Pss", since it's amount of RAM used divided by number of users (so you avoid double-counting when two programs share memory)